# can we apply site custom master page to sharepoint 2013 hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013, apps-development

I want to apply site master page to the sharepoint 2013 hosted app. As I want the same UI as that of host site of that app. So is it possible. How to do that?

Comment: You question is not clear. Are you asking how to apply master page styles to your app or from your app you want to change site master page?

Comment: no I don't want to change site master page I want to apply site master page to my apps. So can we apply site custom master page to sharepoint hosted apps?

Comment: By default the master page of the host web is used in your app, so you don't have to do anything to achieve what you want. Anywhere I install my SharePoint hosed app the styles of the host web are applied.

Comment: Yeah but my question is can we do it or not?